# Why word press is redirected to root domain?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

My project folder is `/var/www/html/project`.

I am run this project using `http://ip/project` is working fine.

But if I click any URL it redirected to `http://ip/file` instead of `http://ip/project/file`.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://ip/project' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://ip/project' );
```

Working with domain is fine, but not working with IP+project URL.

Also, if i am open this URL(`http://ip/project/file`) then it returns 404.

Comment: what did you set the site_url to be?

Comment: Using `define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://ip/project' );`

Comment: well.. there's your answer

Comment: But, this is not working

Comment: But if I click any URL it redirected to `http://ip/file instead` of `http://ip/project/file`.

Comment: It is always best I find to install Wordpress into a predefined Virtual Host

Comment: @SohilSardhara which url you are getting redirected wrong?

Comment: `http://ip/project/file` is redirected to `http://ip/file`.

Comment: @SohilSardhara where in the menu?

Comment: Try re-saving permalinks. That value gets stored in the DB.